# jQuery source through JSLint

Tags: jquery

I'm running jQuery source from [bit.ly/jqsource](http://bit.ly/jqsource) through the laxest configuration of JSLint, but I still get errors. One is the following:

`Problem at line 365 character 83: Expected a conditional expression and instead saw an assignment.`

`if ( deep && copy && ( jQuery.isPlainObject(copy) || (copyIsArray = jQuery.isArray(copy)) ) ) {`

How can this be corrected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would you want to "correct" a perfectly valid line of code? It is just a rather compact way to combine the boolean logic and storing of a value.

The way to achieve the same behaviour without an assignment inside the if statement would be rather ugly:

```
if(deep && copy) {
    var isPlain = jQuery.isPlainObject(copy);
    if(!isPlain) {
        copyIsArray = jQuery.isArray(copy)
    }
    if(isPlain || copyIsArray) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

---

The reason why jslint complains is that `if(foo = 'bar')` instead of `if(foo == 'bar')` is a common error. Some people actually use yoda-style `if('bar' == foo)` to get an error if they forget the second `=`.

Comment: I'm curious about what the problem actually is, really. If there no problem, why is lint shouting?

Comment: Because it thinks you possibly wanted to use `==` instead of `=`

Comment: Lint shouts about all sorts of things that aren't actually problems per se - just cases where there could be performance tweaks, or where some archaic browser had trouble parsing a particular syntax. Or sometimes because Douglas Crockford just decided code should be written a particular way.

Comment: +1 because this is the shortest that the original can be unwrapped to without the inline assignment and still yield identical behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Either `copyIsArray = jQuery.isArray(copy)` should be `copyIsArray == jQuery.isArray(copy)` (conditional rather than assignment)

Or you should do the assignment first:

```
if ( deep && copy && ( jQuery.isPlainObject(copy) || jQuery.isArray(copy) ) ) {
    copyIsArray = jQuery.isArray(copy);
```

Slightly ugly duplication of `jQuery.isArray(copy)`. Oh well.

Example resources:
Conditional: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp
Assignment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp

Comment: The assignment is correct. And your code results in the function being called even if it's not necessary at all (i.e. your code results in different behaviour than the original code)

Comment: This code may not work when `copy` is `null` or `undefined`, whereas the original protects from that because the original code tests `copy` before it executes `isArray(copy)`.

Comment: @jfriend00 true. I'll rectify that.

Comment: The only difference I can see is that copyIsArray will be assigned if `deep` is false, where it wouldn't have before. Not something I would expect to be a problem, but you're right it's not absolutely equivalent. Didn't understand your point about "the original did not".

Comment: Oh I get what you mean now. If `jQuery.isPlainObject(copy)` is `true` then `copyIsArray` would never be defined. Well.. whatever. @ThiefMaster's is the perfect one then. Apart from it could be in less lines if he didn't assign `isPlain` before testing `jQuery.isPlainObject(copy)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are assiging a variable with one = sign rather than comparing it.

```
if ( deep && copy && ( jQuery.isPlainObject(copy) || (copyIsArray **===** jQuery.isArray(copy)) ) )
```

Comment: This code is not supposed to do a comparison! So that would actually break it.